Multiple-paragraph block quotation
I'm currently working on editing an academic paper in APA-7 format for a friend. This paper has a multiple-paragraph block-quote in it (specifically, the entire text of the short manifesto "The Fellowship of the Unashamed".)
For now, I have tentatively formatted it like regular text indented 0.5". Here's an example, using lorem ipsum text:

Is this correct? If not, how should I format it?

Would the downvoter care to explain his or her reasoning?

This is correct as explained in the Publication Manual or on the APA Style website:

Format quotations of 40 words or more as block quotations:

Do not use quotation marks to enclose a block quotation.
Start a block quotation on a new line and indent the whole block 0.5 in. from the left margin.
Double-space the entire block quotation.
Do not add extra space before or after it.
If there are additional paragraphs within the quotation, indent the first line of each subsequent paragraph an additional 0.5 in. See an example in Section 8.27 of the Publication Manual.
Either (a) cite the source in parentheses after the quotation’s final punctuation or (b) cite the author and year in the narrative before the quotation and place only the page number in parentheses after the quotation’s final punctuation.
Do not add a period after the closing parenthesis in either case.


